Is there something like a compiler switch in flutter/dart telling if this is a debug build
I have a section of my flutter/dart code that I want to include only when building for debugging. I could create a custom define like this:
import 'dart:developer';

void main() {
  #if DEBUG
  log('This message will only be printed in debug mode');
  #endif

  // Other code that runs in both debug and release modes
}

...and use it like this...
flutter build apk --dart-define=DEBUG=true
But, it would be better if I didn't have to remember to set that flag. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Some way or another you will have to tell the compiler that you are building in debug mode or release mode.  The easiest way that I can think of is to create two batch files (one for debug and one for release) which contain the correct compiler invocation.

dart-define seems ideal.  you need to do something explicitly to indicate intent... "this is a debug build".  The toolchain cannot intuit your intent magically. :)

The flag mentioned by @nlykk12 is the one you need - it works out of the box.
In your example it would be:
import 'dart:developer';

void main() {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    log('This message will only be printed in debug mode');
  }

  // Other code that runs in both debug and release modes
}

To build it in debug mode you would only need:
flutter build apk --debug

To make sure you're building in a release mode:
flutter build apk --release

* (the --release and --debug) flags work for other distributions, not only apk.
